# Update model from Index action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my User controllers Index view I have a table with usernames and some quick controls, such as a checkbox named "Lock". I want to submit a call to toggle a users "Lock" status when I check/uncheck this checkbox.

Is the correct procedure to make separate actions in the controller for each checkbox (I have a couple per line), or should I make one Action that takes a parameter for which attribute to update on the model? (/User/ToggleLock/{id}, /User/ToggleAttr/{id} vs /User/Toggle/{id}/{attr})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `POST /Users/ToggleLock/{id}` or two actions: `POST /Users/Lock/{id}` and `POST /Users/Unlock/{id}`